# Computer freeze with on full screen

Tags: 16.04, google-chrome, games, steam

I'm running ubuntu 16.04 and always when i go full screen my keyboard freeze and then my screen would freeze as well. I've tried on chrome when i'm for example on netflix or when i'm playing games on steam.

Comment: When this freeze happens can you go to a terminal? Ctrl-Alt-F1? This would say that just X has frozen, not a total system crash.

Comment: yes, actually i just try to use the terminal and it worked the thing is that for example i was playing payday 2 and it freeze and then my mouse pointer wouldn't work nor the game itself.

Comment: So it may be a problem with the configuration of your display driver. What is your display? Do you know what driver you are using? Do you have an xorg.conf file (see `man xorg.conf` for locations)?

Comment: Does it happen if you use less graphic-intensive apps full-screen - like your browser?

Comment: yes, when i'm for example on netflix and i put full screen, it would happen the same

Comment: I meant a non-video app

Comment: some times, i just tried and it's still running smoothly but some times it would freeze too

Comment: Same problem here.